# Upload results for cucumber scenario outline in jira using jenkins

Tags: cucumber, jira, scenarios

I have a scenario outline with multiple data, once the test cases are completed it generates json report, and when i try to upload it on jira it shows result for just one test case not for each data.
I want to see the result of each data under that scenario outline. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide additional information: which dependencies, which versions, which report are you using?

Comment: @Marit, i am using protractor cucumber report  to generate json.

Comment: Please add more information to the question.

Comment: JiraTestExecutionID
Feature:Dummy


    @JiraTestCaseID
    Scenario Outline: Verify data displayed under  Filter
        Given Logged in with <role>
        And Navigate to home
        Then Validate data displayed under Account Filter for <role>
        Examples:
            | role |
            | User1 |
            | User2|
            |User3 |
above is my feature file, my this test case runs for 3 different data, but when i upload the json in jira xray, it shows result of only one random data. i want to see the result for all three